# w2ui grid inline edit enter-key behaviour

Tags: grid, w2ui

when inline-editing a text column in the w2ui.grid the ENTER key applies the change AND starts editing one row below.

How can I prevent the editing of the line below, but only apply the changes to the current row?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by cancelling the edit event if the previous keycode was ENTER.

```
w2ui.grid.onEditField = function(event){
  if(event.originalEvent.keyCode === 13){
     event.preventDefault();
  }
};
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ty77umx1/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike. That does exactly what I need it to do.